# Replace uploaded image with placeholder image permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-file-upload

I've been trying to give functionality of replacing image with my uploaded placeholder image so that my client's don't need to login at the backend of (any CMS) and almost all of them are non-techies.

The following piece of code below will display the placeholder image along with the "upload file button". Once they upload their image, I will delete the choose file option. Is there any possibility of storing their uploaded image somewhere in the folder of the website?

HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='remove' value='remove' class='hide'/>
<input type='file' id="imgInp" /><br>
<img width="230px" id="blah" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/No_pub.svg/150px-No_pub.svg.png" alt="your image" />
```

JS:

```
$('#blah').show();
$('#remove').hide();  
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        if( $('#imgInp').val()!=""){

            $('#remove').show();
            $('#blah').show('slow');
      }
        else    {
                     $('#remove').hide();
        $('#blah').hide('slow');
        }
        readURL(this);
    });


    $('#remove').click(function(){
          $('#imgInp').val('');
          $(this).hide();
          $('#blah').hide('slow');
 $('#blah').attr('src','http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/No_pub.svg/150px-No_pub.svg.png');
});
```

Check out here [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vbrHA/30/)

Comment: Sure, you need a backend for that.

Answer (score -1):

try using this

```
<input id="src" type="file"/>
<input type="button" id="rem" value="remove" style="visibility:hidden;" onclick="myfun()">
<img id="target" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/No_pub.svg/150px-No_pub.svg.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;"/> 

<script>
function showImage(src,target) {
var fr=new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(e) { target.src = this.result; };
src.addEventListener("change",function() {
fr.readAsDataURL(src.files[0]);
document.getElementById("src").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("rem").style.visibility = "visible";

});

}
var src = document.getElementById("src");
var target = document.getElementById("target");
showImage(src,target);
function myfun(){
target.src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/No_pub.svg/150px-No_pub.svg.png";
document.getElementById("src").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("rem").style.visibility = "hidden";
};
</script>
```